# jsp error with an if statement: ") Expected ; Expected"

Tags: java, jsp

I have some jsp code:

```
<% 
if((Integer.parseInt((rs.getString("setter")).trim())==1) and 
    (Integer.parseInt((rs.getString("scrutinizer")).trim())==1))
{
  out.println("Both") 
} 
else if(Integer.parseInt((rs.getString("setter")).trim())==1)
{
  out.println("Question Setter"); 
}
else if(Integer.parseInt((rs.getString("scrutinizer")).trim())==1)               
{
  out.println("Scrutinizer"); 
}

%>
```

I get this error:

```
  ) Expected 
  ; Expected
  else without if Illegal Start of type. missing return statement
```

What is the error message trying to say?

Comment: The logical 'AND' operator is `&&`, not `and`.

Comment: An advice would be using an IDE such as Netbeans or Eclipse which automatically suggest you syntactical errors,

Comment: There is no such thing as an "if loop".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 if((Integer.parseInt((rs.getString("setter")).trim())==1) && (Integer.parseInt((rs.getString("scrutinizer")).trim())==1))
{
  out.println("Both") 
}
```

You are missing a semicolon. Also, in Java `AND` is denoted as `&&`:

```
 if((Integer.parseInt((rs.getString("setter")).trim())==1) && (Integer.parseInt((rs.getString("scrutinizer")).trim())==1))
{
  out.println("Both");
}
```

Comment: Will the code compile?Op is telling the runtime error .If the code will not compile how the OP got runtime error

Comment: @javaBeginner: That seems to be JSP. When I used to work with Java code in JSP it was usually (if memory serves) compiled when needed, hence the runtime error.

Comment: Though its jsp still it will not compile first,I mean to say that how can the server create .class file(from jsp to servlet then .class file

Answer (score 0):

Use `&&` instead of `and`.
put `;` after `out.println("Both")` line
Like this `out.println("Both") ;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the "AND" and replace it with && instead.

You're also missing a semi colon at the end of the print both line.

Answer (score 0):

```
<% 
 if(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("setter")).trim()==1 && Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("scrutinizer")).trim()==1)
{
  out.println("Both");
} 
else if(Integer.parseInt((rs.getString("setter")).trim())==1)
{
  out.println("Question Setter"); 
}
else if(Integer.parseInt((rs.getString("scrutinizer")).trim())==1)               
{
  out.println("Scrutinizer"); 
} 
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You get **Expected ;**, because you forgot a **;**. You should have this:

```
out.println("Both");
```

instead of: `out.println("Both")`

You should be using the operator **&&** here instead of **and**:

```
if((Integer.parseInt((rs.getString("setter")).trim())==1) and (Integer.parseInt((rs.getString("scrutinizer")).trim())==1))
```

the corrected code should look like this:

```
<% if((Integer.parseInt((rs.getString("setter")).trim())==1) && (Integer.parseInt((rs.getString("scrutinizer")).trim())==1))
{
  out.println("Both"); 
} 
else if(Integer.parseInt((rs.getString("setter")).trim())==1)
{
  out.println("Question Setter"); 
}
else if(Integer.parseInt((rs.getString("scrutinizer")).trim())==1)               
{
  out.println("Scrutinizer"); 
} %>
```